# Exclude Option for Prefix or Suffix Filters in AWS Lambda Event Sources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

In AWS Lambda if I create a event source with a suffix filter like `.jpg` for example, and I upload a `.jpg` the lambda function kicks off and it creates a thumbnail called `xyz_thumbnail.jpg`.  However, the problem is that the lambda process will kick off again once it detects `xyz_thumbnail.jpg` being uploaded to the same bucket.  So I end up with an endless loop of images i.e. (`xyz_thumbnail_thumbnail.jpg`, `xyz_thumbnail_thumbnail_thumbnail.jpg`, `xyz_thumbnail_thumbnail_thumbnail_thumbnail.jpg`) until the functions times out and dies.

So my question is how can I filter/exclude any Suffixes with `_thumbnail.jpg` and add that to the event source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no 'exclude' options that I'm aware of, but there are simple solutions:

1. write the thumbnails to a different path e.g. /img/thumbs/, or
2. in the Lambda function ignore any object whose name is of the form xyz_thumbnail.jpg (and for which there is an object named xyz.jpg if you want to be extra cautious)

I prefer the former. It's cleaner to store auto-generated files independently of the source files.

Comment: Ended up making different paths.  Thanks.